# how to change default constructor parameters of a method in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, methods

I just made a void method that takes couple of values for GridBagLayout and set them to the GridBagConstraints. Here is the method:

```
public void gridBag(GridBagConstraints c, int fill, int gridx, int gridy, Insets insets){
        c.fill = fill;
        c.gridx = gridx;
        c.gridy = gridy;
        c.insets = insets;
}
```

Whenever I try to use this method in other classes, it shows the auto-filled version of the method like this:

```
style.gridBag(c, WIDTH, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
```

when I replace each one of there parameters, it works perfectly, and there is no any error. But I am just wondering why does it show `WIDTH` and not `gridx` or `gridy` etc instead for the default value.

Any idea how to change these?

Comment: you are using the autocomplete. You probably a integer variable called WIDTH; And by the naming conventions it's probably a constant (static final ...)

Comment: that is simply provided by editor in your IDE when you choose auto complete.